# alasql parses time from excel but I need only string

Tags: excel, alasql

I'm using alaSQL to parse data from excel. in excel, I have field named: "text" and output field is "word", here I have 3 row,

`abc
test
11:30`

third is time but I need to parse as string, now it parses directly and result is: `0.479166666666667`
please, give me advice, how to parse as string?

this is my query:

`select text word from xlsx('path/to/excel' ,{ headers:true })`

Comment: Please add the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code/snippet for this project? It would help alot to better answer your question.

**Before:**

select text word from xlsx('path/to/excel' ,{ headers:true })

**After:**

SELECT text from xlsx('path/to/excel',{headers:true});

I would assume your trying to get the field/column "text" and get the table row "word".

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the date and time first. Take a look at this link.
[Parse date and time form excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229494/converting-excel-date-serial-number-to-date-using-javascript/16233621#16233621)

Comment: Link-only answers are not good, better to include parts of the solution here