# Browsers, time zones, Chrome 67 Error (historic timezone changes)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, browser

I've updated Chrome to 67 version. And I get an error with the date

==============

**Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0**

```
new Date("1900-01-01T00:00:00").getTimezoneOffset() 

-180

new Date("2018-05-30T00:00:00").getTimezoneOffset()

-180
```

**Microsoft Internet Explorer 11.48.17134.0**

```
new Date("1900-01-01T00:00:00").getTimezoneOffset() 

-180


new Date("2018-05-30T00:00:00").getTimezoneOffset() 

-180
```

**Mozilla Firefox 60.0.1**

```
new Date("1900-01-01T00:00:00").getTimezoneOffset() 

-180

new Date("2018-05-30T00:00:00").getTimezoneOffset() 

-180
```

**Chrome  67.0.3396.62**

```
new Date("1900-01-01T00:00:00").getTimezoneOffset() 

-150

new Date("2018-05-30T00:00:00").getTimezoneOffset()

-180
```

======================

**-150 in Chrome 67...**

**Another Example (Chrome 67):**

```
new Date("1900-01-01T00:00:00");

Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT+0230 (Moscow Standard Time)
```

======================

With Chrome 67, time zones began incorrect (+0230, was: +0300)

Please Tell me?

What Can I Do ?

The situation is very important! All code I must to rewrite...

======================

Comment: Historical dates, times and timezones are extremely complex if you want to do accurate calculations. They're still a bit of a mess today but far simpler than they used to be. You can't expect a javascript implementation to contain all offsets for all dates for all time zones and regions (particularly when in javascript "locale" is actually a language code, not a location). If you want that, use a library with a suitable database of accurate offsets based on locations (not languages), like the IANA time zone database..

Comment: RobG, Thank You! Can you say some libraries (in javascript) with a suitable database... ?

Comment: Requests for external resources are off topic here. You might start with [*moment timezone*](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/), which is an extension to moment.js and uses data from the IANA time zone database. However, I don't know how far back support for historical data goes nor how extensive or accurate it is.

Comment: Thank You! I've adapted code with momentjs. And I get another problem. Client has learned with time zones. No problem on client with "1900-01-01T00:00:00+02:30", But I have a problem with Date from server "1900-01-01T00:00:00+03:00". It becomes 1899 year, minus 30 minutes! How Can I Solve it ? 
I've learned client with Chrome 67, and How client will work with another browsers? 
Excuse me for my English!

Comment: @Alexey: That's a separate problem, and one you need to give a lot more context about, in a new question. RobG and I have explained why you might see different offsets, *particularly* for date/time values a long time ago. That's what this question was about. If you want to know how to best handle that, you need to provide more information about what you're trying to do and what code you have.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to assume you're in the Europe/Moscow time zone - that seems likely given the output you've provided.

In 1900, the Europe/Moscow time zone had an offset of +02:30:17, [according to the IANA time zone database](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/eb4b696c17b0366ab5a0b4c77b527613fef295d8/europe#L2629). Presumably Chrome is rounding down to 02:30 to avoid sub-minute offsets, but it's returning appropriate data as far as I can see. The offset in Russia first became a whole number of hours in 1919, at least according to the IANA database.

Arguably you should be asking why the *other* browsers are not doing that - but more likely, you should change your code to not ask for time zone information prior to 1970. The IANA database aims to provide accurate data from the Unix epoch onwards; anything earlier is very much "best effort". From the [theory file](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/theory.html):

> Clock transitions before 1970 are recorded for each such location, because most systems support timestamps before 1970 and could misbehave if data entries were omitted for pre-1970 transitions. However, the database is not designed for and does not suffice for applications requiring accurate handling of all past times everywhere, as it would take far too much effort and guesswork to record all details of pre-1970 civil timekeeping. Although some information outside the scope of the database is collected in a file backzone that is distributed along with the database proper, this file is less reliable and does not necessarily follow database guidelines.

In terms of why you're seeing this with Chrome 67 if you weren't seeing it with previous versions of Chrome - I wonder whether Chrome has just started bundling IANA time zone data rather than using the OS data.

Comment: This behavior is determined by recent changes in ECMA spec and it's implementation (seems that those changes are implemented only in Chrome so far) - source: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/572148

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issues while using the `new Date("..")`; constructor. (also since Chrome version changed)

A note from of [MDN Date Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) :

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

Perhaps it is possible in your code to use an other Date constrcutor like:

```
 new Date(Date.UTC(96, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```