# new Date() broken on Chrome 67

Tags: javascript

Starting Chrome 67 (full version is 67.0.3396.87), I am experiencing weird behaviour with creation of a new Date object. Smallest reproducible case, goes something like:

```
    <html>
    <body>    
    <script>    alert(new Date(-62135596800000));        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

On Firefox 60.0.2 the alert message is:

`Mon Jan 01 0001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`

On Internet Explorer 11 and Edge 41.16299.461.0, the alert message is same as Firefox:

```
Mon Jan 01 0001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

However, on Chrome 67 I see:

```
Sun Dec 31 0000 23:58:45 GMT-0001 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

**Edit:** [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gc74dqbL/)

**Edit2** Turns out it's nothing to do with Microsoft's library.

Comment: FWIW I could replicate this (I've been looking at the orange "update" arrow in Chrome all day, this seemed a good time to hit it) - [quick JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teu0a84g/) before I updated, in 66 I saw Jan 01, after update to 67 I get Dec 31 etc.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Can I include your fiddle in my question?

Comment: Sure, no problems

Comment: FYI you also see the same thing if you just put `new Date(-62135596800000)` in the console, so looks like it's actually the date handling in Chrome that's changed somewhere rather than anything MS script specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a JavaScript Date object with a set timezone without using a string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s)

Comment: Your `alert()` call implicitly converts the date instance to a string. If you use `alert(model.SampleDayTime.toUTCString())` instead, then you explicitly request that the browser give you UTC time instead of the default local time.

Comment: @Pointy what timezone is 1 minute and 15 seconds off?

Comment: @MattiPrice I agree that something odd is going on.

Comment: The MS script ... is it purposed to run on browser?

Comment: [A bug report has already been filed for this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=852298).

Comment: @JamesThorpe Will have to follow the bug report. I wonder if it is something to do with BigInt -> https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/nic67#bigint?

Comment: Perhaps, but you'd hope not as the number you're using is still well above `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`!

Comment: @JamesThorpe I don't think it's actually a bug. See my answer below

Comment: @MattiPrice Good catch, if they've started using more accurate historical data that may well explain it.  I hate timezones :P

Comment: [Another issue where it's being discussed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849724).

Comment: [And another](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849404) where it's specifically been marked as wontfix.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I think that saying needs to be updated.. "There are 3 things that are difficult in computer science. Naming things, Cache invalidation, Timezones, and off by one errors"

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the response to that bug report, I think this is actually due to Chrome possibly including IANA timezone information. [Browsers, time zones, Chrome 67 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609860/browsers-time-zones-chrome-67-error)

For example, when I run that fiddle, I get `Sun Dec 31 0000 18:09:24 GMT-0550 (Central Standard Time)` which corresponds to the IANA entry `Zone America/Chicago    -5:50:36 -  LMT 1883 Nov 18 12:09:24`.

So this is a "feature" not a bug I think. They are using the more "accurate" historical time offsets instead of current day time offsets for historical dates.

You can view the data here : https://github.com/eggert/tz just look for your appropriate world location file and try and avoid all the commented out lines unless you are morbidly curious about the history of your time zones.

What you can do to "fix" it so it display more or less correctly is to call `.toUTCString()` on the `Date` object which will force it to UTC time and display `Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT` as @Pointy pointed out in the comments on the initial question.

Comment: @Pointy this mean's that your bit about `.toUTCString()` actually does fix it since it knows how to convert from some weird fraction of an hour offset!

Comment: Well the point of my comment was that relying on client time zone in general was probably not a good idea for the OP.

Comment: One thing not mentioned much in this question and its comments+answers is the fact that the OP is working with a really weird timestamp for some reason.

Comment: @Pointy definitely true, and would actually solve the OP's problem. I'm going to edit that in if that's cool with you.

Answer (score -2):

Your code, [as long as MS's one](https://gist.github.com/t1gor/f3a127b7d43069a69ed33ebf9cc90c12#file-microsoftajax-js-L2165), doesn't know anything about the timezone, so I assume Chrome takes the default one.

I guess it should be better if you create your date as below:

```js
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second));
```

Comment: There's no timezone in an epochal timestamp like -62135596800000. That's always interpreted as an offset from a fixed point in time (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00)

Comment: Fair enough. Point noted and sorry for the confusion.