# Luxon parses incorrect date from ISO string

Tags: javascript, date, luxon

When I parse `1909-01-01T03:00:00Z` with Luxon using `DateTime.fromISO` on a PC with the -3 GMT timezone instead of getting the January 1st 1909 at midnight I get December 31st 1908 22:43. I am doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: See [*Browsers, time zones, Chrome 67 Error (historic timezone changes)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609860/browsers-time-zones-chrome-67-error-historic-timezone-changes). What location are you using for the offset? You can check historic offsets for various locations at [*timeanddate.com*](https://www.timeanddate.com).

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Luxon docs I managed to find a solution. Parsing the string as UTC then converting it to local with `keepLocalTime` kept the correct date.

```
 let date = DateTime.fromISO(dateString, { zone: 'utc' });
 date = fecha.setZone('local', { keepLocalTime: true });
```

Comment: where the fetcha comes from?