# JS Date UTC 1893 has strange representation in local time (Europe/Berlin) compared to 1894

Tags: javascript, date

I realized when printing Dates from UTC that from 1893 to 1894 there are 6 minutes diff and 32 seconds.

Why is that?

`new Date(Date.UTC(1894,0,1))`
`// Mon Jan 01 1894 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

`new Date(Date.UTC(1893,0,1))`
`// Mon Jan 01 1893 00:53:28 GMT+0053 (Central European Standard Time)`

My timezone is "Europe/Berlin"

Comment: Historical time zones are like that. They weren't always unified, so you could have time zones that drift with minutes. They might even differ between different cities.

Comment: Is it browser specific? Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609860/browsers-time-zones-chrome-67-error-historic-timezone-changes ?

Comment: From [*timeanddate.com*](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin), the offset in Berlin for 1850 to 1892 was +0:53:28, in 1893 it was +0:06:32, then from 1894 to 1899 it was +1:00:00.