# EPiserver Forms submission issue after Upgrade to latest within Optimizely 11

Tags: episerver, optimizely, episerver-forms

We have recently upgraded a EpiForms & a few other packages to the latest within Optimizely 11.
Here’s a screenshot of  BEFORE(PROD) & AFTER(PREP) package upgrades:

[image]

We have found an issue with Episerver forms submission specifically related to **Show a summary confirmation message after submission.**
Here’s the issue in detail:

If the **“Show a summary confirmation message after submission”** property is checked/enabled (screenshot #1), the form does not send when “submit” is clicked. It acts like it submitted with the conformation message (screenshot #2), but I did not receive the confirmation emails as well as I do not see the entry in the “Form submissions” view in Epi

I did at few form submissions and only see entries within form submissions list where “Show a summary confirmation message after submission” property is unchecked/disabled.

screenshot #1

[image]

[image]

However, in PROD, if the “Show a summary confirmation message after submission” property is checked/enabled, the conformation message is a modal with “OK” and “Cancel” buttons (screenshot #3). If “OK” is clicked, the emails send. This leads me to believe that in PREP, the absence of the “OK” and “Cancel” buttons do not allow for the form submission to be finalized, hence the forms do not send.
Screenshot #3

[image]

Lastly, Here’s what is captured on the console when Show a summary confirmation message after submission is checked.

[image]

Here's EpiserverFormsSamples.js

```
(function ($) {
$.extend(true, epi.EPiServer.Forms, {
    // this dateFormats is for using in Samples only
    Samples: {
        // pickerFormat will be used for jQuery datepicker validation,
        // while friendlyFormat will show in validation message for user.
        DateFormats: {
            "en-us": {
                "pickerFormat": "mm/dd/yy",
                "friendlyFormat": "MM/dd/yyyy"
            },
            "sv-se": {
                "pickerFormat": "yy-mm-dd",
                "friendlyFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            },
            "nb-no": {
                "pickerFormat": "dd.mm.yy",
                "friendlyFormat": "dd.MM.yyyy"
            },
            "da-dk": {
                "pickerFormat": "dd-mm-yy",
                "friendlyFormat": "dd-MM-yyyy"
            },
            "de-de": {
                "pickerFormat": "dd.mm.yy",
                "friendlyFormat": "dd.MM.yyyy"
            },
            "nl-nl": {
                "pickerFormat": "d-m-yy",
                "friendlyFormat": "d-M-yyyy"
            },
            "fi-fi": {
                "pickerFormat": "d.m.yy",
                "friendlyFormat": "d.M.yyyy"
            },

            "fr-fr": {
                "pickerFormat": "dd/mm/yy",
                "friendlyFormat": "dd/MM/yyyy"
            }
        }
    }
});

var _utilsSvc = epi.EPiServer.Forms.Utils,
    originalGetCustomElementValue = epi.EPiServer.Forms.Extension.getCustomElementValue,
    originalBindCustomElementValue = epi.EPiServer.Forms.Extension.bindCustomElementValue,
    dateTimePickerTypes = {
        datePicker: "datepicker",
        timePicker: "timepicker",
        dateTimePicker: "datetimepicker"
    },

    language = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage, // on iOS naviagtor.language is in lower case (ex: en-us)
    dateFormatSettings = epi.EPiServer.Forms.Samples.DateFormats[language.toLowerCase()] || epi.EPiServer.Forms.Samples.DateFormats["en-us"],
    dateFormat = dateFormatSettings.pickerFormat,


    dateTimeValidate = function (fieldName, fieldValue, validatorMetaData) {
        // this function is used to validate visitor's data value in ViewMode

        // the fieldValue return by get getCustomElementValue already contains validate information,
        // just check fieldValue.isValid and return along with error message

        if (typeof fieldValue === 'object' && fieldValue.isValid == false) {

            var friendlyFormat = dateFormatSettings.friendlyFormat,
                message = _utilsSvc.stringFormat(validatorMetaData.model.message, [friendlyFormat]);

            return {
                isValid: false,
                message: message
            };
        }

        return {
            isValid: true
        };
    },

    dateTimeRangeValidate = function (fieldName, fieldValue, validatorMetaData) {
        // this function is used to validate visitor's data value in ViewMode

        // the fieldValue return by get getCustomElementValue already contains validate information,
        // just check fieldValue.isValid and return along with error message
        if (typeof fieldValue === 'object' && fieldValue.isValid == false) {
            return {
                isValid: false,
                message: validatorMetaData.model.message
            };
        }
        // if value is empty, then let the required validator take the decision
        if (fieldValue == "") {
            return {
                isValid: true
            };
        }

        var values = fieldValue.split('|');
        if (!values || values.length < 2) {
            return {
                isValid: false
            };
        }

        var startDateTimeString = values[0],
            endDateTimeString = values[1],
            startDate = Date.parse(startDateTimeString),
            endDate = Date.parse(endDateTimeString);

        if (!startDate || !endDate || startDate >= endDate) {
            return {
                isValid: false,
                message: validatorMetaData.model.message
            };
        }

        return {
            isValid: true
        };
    };

addressesValidate = function validateAddress(fieldName, fieldValue, validatorMetaData) {
    var validateEnpoint = '/ExternalValidate/ValidateAddress',
        validateResult = {
            isValid: false
        };

    $.ajax({
        url: validateEnpoint,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.parse(fieldValue),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (valid) {
            validateResult.isValid = valid;
            if (!validateResult.isValid) validateResult.message = validatorMetaData.model.message;
        },
        error: function () {
            validateResult.isValid = false;
        }
    });
    return validateResult;
}


// extend the EpiForm JavaScript API in ViewMode
$.extend(true, epi.EPiServer.Forms, {
    /// extend the Validator to validate Visitor's value in Clientside.
    /// Serverside's Fullname of the Validator instance is used as object key (Case-sensitve) to lookup the Clientside validate function.        
    Validators: {
        "EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Validation.AddressValidator": addressesValidate,
        "EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Validation.DateTimeRangeValidator": dateTimeRangeValidate,
        "EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Validation.DateTimeValidator": dateTimeValidate,
        "EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Validation.DateValidator": dateTimeValidate,
        "EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Validation.TimeValidator": dateTimeValidate,
        "EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Validation.RecaptchaValidator": function () {
            return {};
        }
    },

    /// BETA
    /// value store in localStorage and value displaying for Visitor can be different. This function return the value for display to Visitor.
    CustomBindingElements: {
        "EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Elements.DateTimeElementBlock": function (elementInfo, val) {

            // Datetime with format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmTZD(ISO-8601) "2018-08-07T00:00+07:00"
            if (!val || $.type(val) != "string" || !Date.parse(val)) {
                return;
            }

            var picker = {
                    settings: {
                        dateFormat: dateFormat
                    }
                },
                dateTime = new Date(val),
                dateString = $.datetimepicker.formatDate(picker.settings.dateFormat, dateTime),
                //we only support time with AM/PM -> 'en-US' is used.
                timeString = dateTime.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                    hour: '2-digit',
                    minute: '2-digit',
                    hour12: true
                }),
                timeStringWithLeadingZero = ("0" + timeString).slice(-8); // with format "hh:mm tt", toLocaleString return hour without leading zero


            switch (elementInfo.pickerType) {
                case dateTimePickerTypes.datePicker:
                    return dateString;
                case dateTimePickerTypes.dateTimePicker:
                    return dateString + " " + timeStringWithLeadingZero;
                case dateTimePickerTypes.timePicker:
                    return timeStringWithLeadingZero;
            }
        },

        "EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Elements.DateTimeRangeElementBlock": function (elementInfo, val) {
            if (!val || $.type(val) != "string") {
                return;
            }
            var dateTimes = val.split("|");
            if (!dateTimes || dateTimes.length != 2) {
                return;
            }
            var startDate = dateTimes[0],
                endDate = dateTimes[1],
                startDateString = this["EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Elements.DateTimeElementBlock"](elementInfo, startDate),
                endDateString = this["EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Elements.DateTimeElementBlock"](elementInfo, endDate);

            return startDateString + ' : ' + endDateString;
        },

        "EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Elements.AddressesElementBlock": function (elementInfo, val) {
            if (!val) {
                return;
            }
            var locationObj = JSON.parse(val),
                locationString = locationObj.address;

            if (locationObj.street) {
                locationString += ', ' + locationObj.street;
            }
            if (locationObj.city) {
                locationString += ', ' + locationObj.city;
            }
            if (locationObj.state) {
                locationString += ', ' + locationObj.state;
            }
            if (locationObj.postalCode) {
                locationString += ', ' + locationObj.postalCode;
            }
            if (locationObj.country) {
                locationString += ', ' + locationObj.country;
            }
            return locationString;
        }
    },

    Extension: {

        // OVERRIDE, this function to show jQuery Dialog as Summarized Dialog before submission
        showSummarizedText: function (data, workingFormInfo, ignoreFields, shouldBeHiddenKeys) {
            // workingFormInfo.ElementsInfo: contains friendlyName for each field code
            // ignoreFields: are (System) fields should be ignored
            // shouldBeHiddenKeys: are fields which should not be shown (hidden field, tracking code, ...)
            // to determine field should be display or not, check $("[name=" + key + "]", workingFormInfo.$workingForm).hasClass("FormHideInSummarized"))

            var $deferred = $.Deferred(),
                summarizedText = this.getSummarizedText(workingFormInfo, data, true);
            // empty text, no need to show the confirm box
            if (!summarizedText || summarizedText.trim() === "") {
                $deferred.resolve(true);

                return $deferred.promise();
            }

            var confirmationResources = epi.EPiServer.Forms.LocalizedResources.samples.confirmationdialog;

            $("<div class=\"Form__ConfirmationDialog\"></div>").html(summarizedText).appendTo(workingFormInfo.$workingForm);

            $(".Form__ConfirmationDialog", workingFormInfo.$workingForm).dialog({
                title: confirmationResources.title,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: [{
                        text: confirmationResources.buttons.ok,
                        click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            $deferred.resolve(true);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: confirmationResources.buttons.cancel,
                        click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            $deferred.resolve(false);
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

            return $deferred.promise();
        },

        // OVERRIDE
        onBeforeSubmit: function (currentForm) {
            return this._getRecaptchaToken(currentForm);
        },

        // get reCaptcha token.
        _getRecaptchaToken: function (form) {
            var $deferred = $.Deferred(),
                $recaptchaElement = $(form).find(".Form__Element.FormRecaptcha");

            // If we don't have recaptcha element -> do nothing.
            if (!$recaptchaElement.hasClass("FormRecaptcha")) {
                $deferred.resolve();
                return $deferred.promise();
            }

            var siteKey = $recaptchaElement.data("epiforms-sitekey");
            // get reCaptcha token to validate in serverside.

            try {
                grecaptcha.execute(siteKey).then(function (token) {
                    $recaptchaElement.attr("g-recaptcha-response", token);
                    $deferred.resolve(token);
                });
            } catch (err) {
                $deferred.resolve();
                return $deferred.promise();
            };

            return $deferred.promise();
        },

        // OVERRIDE, process to get value from datetime picker element
        getCustomElementValue: function ($element) {

            // for datetime picker we always return result in format "2015-12-25 10:30 AM",
            // and depend on picker type (date/time/datetime) we will parse its value later.

            if ($element.hasClass("FormDateTime")) {
                var $input = $('.FormDateTime__Input', $element);
                return this.getCustomDateTimeElementValue($input);
            }

            if ($element.hasClass("FormRecaptcha")) {
                return $element.attr("g-recaptcha-response");
            }

            if ($element.hasClass("FormDateTimeRange")) {
                var $startInput = $('.FormDateTimeRange__Start', $element),
                    $endInput = $('.FormDateTimeRange__End', $element),
                    startDateTime = this.getCustomDateTimeElementValue($startInput),
                    endDateTime = this.getCustomDateTimeElementValue($endInput);

                if (startDateTime.isValid == false || endDateTime.isValid == false) {
                    return {
                        isValid: false
                    };
                }

                // if only startDate or endDate exists, then return invalid
                if (!((startDateTime && endDateTime) || (!startDateTime && !endDateTime))) {
                    return {
                        isValid: false
                    };
                }
                if (!startDateTime && !endDateTime) {
                    return '';
                }
                return startDateTime + '|' + endDateTime;
            }

            if ($element.hasClass("FormAddressElement")) {

                var address = $('.FormAddressElement__Address', $element).first().val(),
                    country = $('.FormAddressElement__Country', $element).first().val(),
                    state = $('.FormAddressElement__State', $element).first().val(),
                    city = $('.FormAddressElement__Locality', $element).first().val(),
                    postalCode = $('.FormAddressElement__ZipCode', $element).first().val(),
                    street = $('.FormAddressElement__Route', $element).first().val();

                return JSON.stringify({
                    address: address,
                    street: street,
                    city: city,
                    state: state,
                    postalCode: postalCode,
                    country: country
                });
            }

            // if current element is not our job, let others process
            return originalGetCustomElementValue.apply(this, [$element]);
        },

        getCustomDateTimeElementValue: function ($element) {
            var dateTimeString = $.trim($element.val()),
                picker = $.datetimepicker._getInst($element[0]),
                timeRegex = "^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\\d) [APap][mM]$";

            if (!dateTimeString) {
                return dateTimeString;
            }

            switch (picker.settings.type) {

                case dateTimePickerTypes.datePicker:
                case dateTimePickerTypes.dateTimePicker:
                    var dateTime;
                    try {
                        // try to parse date with format
                        dateTime = $.datetimepicker.parseDate(picker.settings.dateFormat, dateTimeString);
                    } catch (err) {
                        return {
                            isValid: false
                        };
                    }
                    var result = _utilsSvc.stringFormat("{0}-{1}-{2}", [dateTime.getFullYear(), this.addLeadingZero(dateTime.getMonth() + 1), this.addLeadingZero(dateTime.getDate())]);
                    if (picker.settings.type == dateTimePickerTypes.dateTimePicker) {
                        var dateTimeSegments = dateTimeString.split(" ");

                        if (dateTimeSegments.length < 3) {
                            return {
                                isValid: false
                            };
                        }

                        var timeString = dateTimeSegments[1] + " " + dateTimeSegments[2];
                        if (!_utilsSvc.isMatchedReg(timeString, timeRegex)) {
                            return {
                                isValid: false
                            };
                        }

                        result += " " + timeString;
                    } else {
                        result += " 12:00 AM"; // add fake time string into return results, this will be ignored when rebind data
                    }
                    return this.toISODateTimeString(result);

                case dateTimePickerTypes.timePicker:
                    if (!_utilsSvc.isMatchedReg(dateTimeString, timeRegex)) {
                        return {
                            isValid: false
                        };
                    }
                    var yearString = new Date().getFullYear();
                    return this.toISODateTimeString(yearString + "-01-01 " + dateTimeString); // add fake date string into return results, this will be ignored when rebind data
            }

            return null;
        },

        // convert datetime format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm tt to format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmTZD(ISO-8601)
        // https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
        toISODateTimeString: function (dateTimeString) {

            if (!dateTimeString) {
                return null;
            }

            var dateTimeSegments = dateTimeString.split(" ");
            if (dateTimeSegments.length < 3) {
                return null;
            }

            var dateRegex = "^\\d{4}-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])";
            var dateString = dateTimeSegments[0];
            if (!_utilsSvc.isMatchedReg(dateString, dateRegex)) {
                return null;
            }

            var timeRegex = "^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\\d) [APap][mM]$";
            var timeString = dateTimeSegments[1] + " " + dateTimeSegments[2];
            if (!_utilsSvc.isMatchedReg(timeString, timeRegex)) {
                return null;
            }

            return dateString + "T" + this.convertTo24Hour(timeString) + this.getTimeZoneDesignator(dateString);
        },

        // convert 12h base to 24h base
        convertTo24Hour: function (time) {
            time = time.toLowerCase();
            var hours = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2));
            if (time.indexOf("am") !== -1 && hours === 12) {
                time = time.replace("12", "00");
            }
            if (time.indexOf("pm") !== -1 && hours < 12) {
                time = time.replace(this.addLeadingZero(hours), (hours + 12));
            }
            return time.replace(/(am|pm)/, "").trim();
        },

        // get time zone designator TZD based on TimezoneOffset
        // Firefox and IE don't understand YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm tt format, we should use dateString only (ex:2018-01-01)
        getTimeZoneDesignator: function (dateString) {
            // note: on Chrome getTimeZoneDesignator return different result for different years (2018,1970,1900)
            // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609860/browsers-time-zones-chrome-67-error
            var timeZoneOffset = -(new Date(dateString)).getTimezoneOffset(),
                dif = timeZoneOffset >= 0 ? "+" : "-";

            timeZoneOffset = Math.abs(timeZoneOffset);

            var offsetMinutes = timeZoneOffset % 60,
                offsetHours = (timeZoneOffset - offsetMinutes) / 60;

            return dif + this.addLeadingZero(offsetHours) + ":" + this.addLeadingZero(offsetMinutes);
        },

        // add leading zero to number < 10 (Ex: 9 -> 09, 7-> 07)
        addLeadingZero: function (number) {
            if (number < 10) {
                return "0" + number;
            }
            return number;
        },

        // OVERRIDE, custom binding data for date/time/datetime picker and date-time-range picker
        bindCustomElementValue: function ($element, val) {
            if ($element.hasClass('FormDateTimeRange')) {
                // skip binding value for DateTimeRange when it has invalid value
                if (typeof val != "string") {
                    return;
                }
                var values = val.split('|');
                if (values && values.length < 2) {
                    return;
                }

                var $startEl = $element.find(".FormDateTimeRange__Start"),
                    $endEl = $element.find(".FormDateTimeRange__End"),
                    startPicker = $.datetimepicker._getInst($startEl[0]),
                    startBindingValue = epi.EPiServer.Forms.CustomBindingElements["EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Elements.DateTimeElementBlock"]({
                        pickerType: startPicker.settings.type
                    }, values[0]),
                    endPicker = $.datetimepicker._getInst($endEl[0]),
                    endBindingValue = epi.EPiServer.Forms.CustomBindingElements["EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Elements.DateTimeElementBlock"]({
                        pickerType: endPicker.settings.type
                    }, values[1]);
                $startEl.val(startBindingValue);
                $endEl.val(endBindingValue);
                return;
            }

            if ($element.hasClass('FormDateTime')) {
                var $item = $element.find(".Form__CustomInput");
                if ($item.hasClass("FormDateTime__Input")) {

                    var picker = $.datetimepicker._getInst($item[0]),
                        bindingValue = epi.EPiServer.Forms.CustomBindingElements["EPiServer.Forms.Samples.Implementation.Elements.DateTimeElementBlock"]({
                            pickerType: picker.settings.type
                        }, val);
                    $item.val(bindingValue);
                    return;
                }
            }

            if ($element.hasClass('FormAddressElement')) {
                var $addressEl = $element.find(".FormAddressElement__Address"),
                    $countryEl = $element.find(".FormAddressElement__Country"),
                    $stateEl = $element.find(".FormAddressElement__State"),
                    $cityEl = $element.find(".FormAddressElement__Locality"),
                    $routeEl = $element.find(".FormAddressElement__Route"),
                    $zipEl = $element.find(".FormAddressElement__ZipCode"),
                    addressInfo = JSON.parse(val);
                $countryEl.val(addressInfo.country);
                $zipEl.val(addressInfo.postalCode);
                $stateEl.val(addressInfo.state);
                $cityEl.val(addressInfo.city);
                $routeEl.val(addressInfo.street);
                $addressEl.val(addressInfo.address);
                return;
            }

            // if current element is not our job, let others process
            return originalBindCustomElementValue.apply(this, [$element, val]);
        }
    }
});
```

})($$epiforms || $);

Any help/input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After raising the ticket with Optimizely, here's the response I received from support regarding this defect, which is **also present in Optimizely 12.**

The temporary workaround here is to remove the show summary code in EpiserverFormsSamples.js. To do this, navigate to EpiserverFormsSamples.js located under:

*\modules_protected\EPiServer.Forms.Samples\3.7.1\ClientResources\ViewMode*

and remove the code as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541. also provide line numbers (beginning and end) as text

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there's a bug in EPiServer.Forms.Samples 3.7.1, unless you had any issues with that packet in 3.7.0 there's no reason to upgrade it.

Try downgrading that packet to 3.7.0 and test again.

Comment: Thanks Eric for the response. Downgrading is an option I get that. However, if there's an update available ,the obvious thing is to upgrade it right? Moreover, I am just trying to identify if this is a bug with the new package available to decide on downgrading to the version that works.

Comment: Sure, there are however not real critical fixes between 3.7.0 and 3.7.1 (https://world.optimizely.com/documentation/Release-Notes/). Try to downgrade and see if that fixes this issue.

Comment: I tried downgrading Episerver.Forms.Sample to 3.7.0 but that didn't fix the issue. The whole point of upgrading epi forms in the first place was 
due to https://world.optimizely.com/blogs/phu-nguyen/dates/2023/10/vulnerability-in-episerver-forms/ . I cant downgrade every package related for Epi Forms below 4.30 because of the issue mentioned here.

Comment: What does your EpiserverFormsSamples.js file contain?

Comment: I updated the question with EpiserverFormsSamples.js .

Comment: Is the idea that the client (visitor) should read the method from EpiserverFormsSamples.js? Can it be reached by a visitor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256463/discussion-between-farhin-shaikh-and-eric-herlitz).