# Converting data string with no leading zeros in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, date, d3.js

I'm having difficulty parsing a string into data format using JavaScript.  The issue is that there are no leading zeros.  For example, in my JSON:

> 1/1/1993 is listed as: `33970`

I've tried:

```
function dateMatch(data, value) {
  var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%B %d, %Y");
  var d = formatTime(new Date(data.properties.Sign_Date.toString()));
  console.log(d)
}
```

No luck! What can I try next?

Comment: How is that a date? `33970` doesn't map to `1/1/1993` in any obvious way no matter how many leading zeroes you give it.

Comment: I have no idea.. it was converted from a csv to a geojson file.. and converted automatically.  Hm.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 This might be an issue when the csv is getting parsed into GeoJson. Do you have control over that process?

Comment: @Herohtar 33,970 is a date in the sense that it is the number of days from 1/1/1900 to 1/1/1993;  having said that, I've no idea what part of the overall process is arriving at this conversion, but knowing this might provide a hint or clue of where to look

Comment: @landru27 Hmm, maybe, but both Google and WolframAlpha tell me that the number of days between those dates is 33,968. Exactly 33,970 days before 1/1/1993 is actually 12/30/1899.

Comment: I agree with @TannerEustice, this seems like something you need to look at in whatever is parsing the CSV into GeoJson.

Comment: @Herohtar : I stand corrected; your precision provides a clue:  the internal epoch date for Microsoft Excel is evidently 12/30/1899;  DiamondJoe12 : is perhaps "1/1/1993" shown on the spreadsheet, but your CSV already has "33970", i.e., in the export from the spreadsheet to the CSV file you are working with?  at any rate, I fully agree with the gist of all these comments : there are several places to look in your overall conversion pipeline / process.

Comment: citation for my previous comment : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)  : note, "Technical internal value used by Microsoft Excel; for compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Excel Date Serial Number to Date using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229494/converting-excel-date-serial-number-to-date-using-javascript)