# Convert Date (dd/mm/yyyy) to Excel Serial Number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, date, xlsx

**Description**:

I am generating an Excel file using the **XLSX** on an **Angular Project** (*npm install xlsx*), but I am facing a problem showing a precise date. If I try to use JavaScript date object it somewhow loses precision and show a wrong date. It also fails if I try to use a string corresponding to 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

I figured out that to make the Microsoft Excel have a precise date with the format dd/mm/yyyy, you need to work with Excel Serial Format, that follows a pattern.

Here is some examples of this format:

- **Date:** 01/01/1900 - **Serial:** 1
- **Date:** 02/01/1900 - **Serial:** 2
- **Date:** 09/04/1900 - **Serial:** 100
- **Date:** 26/09/1902 - **Serial:** 1000
- **Date:** 08/09/1913 - **Serial:** 5000
- **Date:** 18/05/1927 - **Serial:** 10000
- **Date:** 24/07/1998 - **Serial:** 36000

*You can try that on Microsoft Excel to check for more examples.

Above here is a prototype of the function I need, that will recevei a date (dd/mm/yyyy) and will return it's serial number equivalent.

```
private JSDateToExcelDate(inDate) {
   if(inDate != null) { 
   //TO DO
   }
}
```

**Additional information:**

The xlsx framework has can modify any cell telling it that value type will be Date. With that in mind all I need is a Date in Serial Number format.

**UPDATE 11/06/2019 - 20:14**

I have found a solution with the following function that provides the number I want. I solved it partialy because the framework XLSX might be changing the value, because I am getting an output as "31/12/1969  21:00:16", witch I found out that is a default output related due to some invalid date.  (*I have created the function on a Angular Project, so it might contains specific syntax*)

```
private JSDateToExcelDate(date) {
    var temp: any;
    temp = new Date(date);
    if(date != "NaN" && date != "Invalid Date") {
      var days = Math.round((temp.setHours(0,0,0,0) - <any>new Date(1899, 11, 30)) / 8.64e7);
      let ret:any = (days).toFixed(10);
      if(!isNaN(ret)) {
        return ret;  
      }
    }
    return '';
  }
```

Comment: did you tried using momentjs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229494/converting-excel-date-serial-number-to-date-using-javascript

Comment: @RafaelLucini I did, but it shows unprecise date on excel

Comment: @RafaelLucini I also have tried that function over that link. It does not work

Comment: @Screll—no. The decimal part is always positive, but the integer number part is negative before 1899-12-30. So 6am on 29 Dec 1899 is -1.25 (i.e. minus 1 day, plus 0.25 days), not -0.75. ;-)

Comment: I have worked on the duplicated link the was placed and was able to built a function that returns the integer Serial Number I need, but the framework XLSX might be changin the value, because it places a default date value over the excel, but if I console.log(MyDate), I will see it's Serial Number correct, I can even pick it and paste on excel Date Field and see the correct date.

Answer (score 1):

```
var start = new Date('1900-01-01')
return (inDate - start)/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

Comment: Timezone? Or maybe `floor` it?

Comment: The epoch is 1899-12-30 00:00:00, and the decimal parts of the value are separate from the integer day part of the value. That is simple for dates after the epoch, but means the two parts must be calculated separately before it.