# Convert Google Sheets date to JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-sheets-api

I'm working with *unformatted* values received via Google Sheets REST API. One of the columns is a timestamp which only reads as a single number. Looks neither like a Unix timestamp nor JS timestamp. For example, `2020-12-09T20:55:14+08:00` comes as `44174.87168438657`.

What is this format and how do I convert it to Unix timestamp or JS `Date`?

Comment: It might be the same as excel which does something weird (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252#:~:text=Excel%20stores%20dates%20as%20sequential,date%20values%20to%20serial%20numbers.)

Comment: I am not a google sheets expert but I think it might be related to this: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093357 (" *If value is a date or time, N returns a generated serial number, based on the number of days since December 30, 1899.* ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SERIAL_NUMBER** outputted by the API is the number of days since December 30, 1899 and the fractional portion (right of the decimal) counts the time as a fraction of the day.

*You could verify the start date by using =TO_DATE in your spreadsheet.*

**Example:**

[image]

To convert the serial date into a Javascript date, you could follow **silkfire's** comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16233621).

### References

[DateTimeRenderOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DateTimeRenderOption)

[TO_DATE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094239)

Comment: If this is like the MS equivalent, you need to be careful with negative numbers. The integer part is -ve days, but the decimal part is +ve time, so -2.25 is 06:00 on 28 Dec 1899 not 18:00 on 27 Dec 1899 (i.e. subtract 2 days then add 0.25 days).