# Google sheets get date value as number problem

Tags: flutter, dart, google-sheets

In google sheets when I insert a date it saves it in the right format
when I get that value I get an int number
I insert this 1/6/2021 & I get that 44202
1/6/2021 => 44202
how to convert this number to date in dart or java or any language

I get it from google sheets API using a package so it gives me a number

https://pub.dev/packages/gsheets

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: how to convert this number to date

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I use dart  language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`44202` refers to the number of days passed since the epoch time used in spreadsheets, which refers to `December 30th, 1899`.

If you want to retrieve the corresponding date in Dart, you can just add this number of days to this epoch date. For example, you could do this:

```
var epoch = new DateTime(1899,12,30);
var currentDate = epoch.add(new Duration(days: 44202));
print(currentDate); // 2021-01-06
```

#### Reference:

- [DateTime class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)

Comment: Good point! It's important to note that google sheets is using a different epoch time.

Answer (score 0):

internaly:

[image]

---

externaly:

```
=TEXT(A1; "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

[image]

Comment: I get it from google sheets api using a package  so it gives me a number

Answer (score 0):

Iamblichus's answer is the right answer but I'd like to add some details about how to convert hours, minutes and seconds, that I found on [this Javascript answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16233621/4191837):

```dart
var fractionalDay = serial - serial.floor() + 0.0000001;
var totalSeconds = (86400 * fractionalDay).floor();
var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
totalSeconds -= seconds;
var hours = (totalSeconds / (60 * 60)).floor();
var minutes = (totalSeconds / 60).floor() % 60;

var epoch = DateTime(1899,12,30);
var currentDate = epoch.add(Duration(days: serial.floor(), hours: hours, minutes: minutes, seconds: seconds));
```

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead  Use this to convert both time and date **Dart Version**!

Formated Date Will be like this **5-12-1992**:

```
 static String? formatSheetDate(String? dateGot) {
    if (dateGot == null || dateGot == '') return null;
    final dateSome = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
        ((double.parse(dateGot) - 25569) * 86400000).toInt(),
        isUtc: true);
    var dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateSome.toString());

    var formatDate = "${dateTime.day}-${dateTime.month}-${dateTime.year}";

    return formatDate;
  }
```

Formated Time Will be like this  **08:20 AM**  :

```
static String? formatSheetTime(String? timeGot) {
    if (timeGot == null || timeGot == '') return null;
    final dateSome = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
        ((double.parse(timeGot) - 25569) * 86400000).toInt(),
        isUtc: true);
    var dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateSome.toString());

    var formattedTime = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(dateTime);

    return formattedTime;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ListView to display items then you could do it like this:

```
******Code in Multiple Lines******
body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: _transazione.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final transazione = _transazione[index];
        final epoch = DateTime(1899, 12, 30);
        final currentDate = epoch.add(Duration(days: (int.tryParse(transazione.data) ?? 0)));
        final formatter = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(currentDate);
        return ListTile(
            title: //...
            subtitle: Text(formatter),
            trailing: //...
        );
    },
),

******Code in One Line:******
subtitle: Text(DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(DateTime(1899, 12, 30).add(Duration(days: (int.tryParse(transazione.data) ?? 0))))),
```