# Flutter get form google sheet but date time can not convert

Tags: json, flutter, datetime

I has setup flutter project get data from my Google sheet ,use Package gsheets 0.2.6 to get data
when I get data use the print to check DateTime , I can verify is correct date time like this "2021-03-11 13:41:05" but when used the

```
factory ShpTable.fromGsheets(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return ShpTable(
DateTime: DateTime.parse(json['DateTime'].toString()),
)}
```

I only can watch datevalue like this "44265.671747685185"
I has tried used

```
DateTime.Parse(json['DateTime'].toString()).toString()
```

but get invalid data format

or

```
DateTime.tryParse(json['DateTime'].toString() ?? '').toString()
```

only feedback null

also I has tried

```
DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(int.Parse(json['DateTime'].toString().trim() )
```

Still not work.
How can i solve this issue?

my list

```
factory ShpTable.fromGsheets(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return ShpTable(
      teamsName: json['TeamsName'].toString().trim(),
      teamOrde: json['TeamOrde'].toString().trim(),
      shpt: json['Shpt'].toString().trim(),
      dp: json['DP'].toString().trim(),
      delivery: json['Delivery'].toString().trim(),
      country: json['Country'].toString().trim(),
      items: int.tryParse(json['Items'] ?? ''),
      orde: json['Orde'].toString().trim(),
      shipTo: json['ShipTo'].toString().trim(),
      shipmentNo: json['ShipmentNo'].toString().trim(),
      shipmentDateTime: json['ShipmentDateTime'].toString().trim(),
      serviceStart: json['Service_Start'].toString().trim(),
      serviceEnd: json['Service_End'].toString().trim(),
      kpi: int.tryParse(json['KPI_Hour'] ?? ''),
      status: json['STATUS'].toString().trim() ,
      shpCondition: json['SHPCondition'].toString().trim(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What is "44265.671747685185" rapresenting? If I convert "2021-03-11 13:41:05" to timestamp it would look somethin like like "1615466465000" so that value is not the unix timestamp

Comment: but used the Excel or Google Sheet you can convert Date String to Date Value, Like 2021-02-28 Datevalue("2021-02-28") ==> 44255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Datevalue on Google sheet the value you are getting is not a Unix timestamp.

I find out on Google sheet you can convert your string date to a Unix timestamp with this formula:

```
=INT((YOURCELL-("1/1/1970"-"1/1/1900"+2))*86400000)
```

Then you have to convert the unix timestamp you get to a DateTime on Flutter.

There it is:

```
String getDate(int UnixTimestamp){
    DateTime date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(UnixTimestamp);
    return date.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I summarized above answer to below code and does not need extra cell in google sheet . it is done only by flutter code :

```
d=DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(((double.parse(YOURCELLVALUE)-25569)*86400000).toInt(),isUtc: true);
```

Comment: Great Ans Works fine! Below is my added  more on point answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72485609/8665703