# How to transform DATEVALUE into date using excel javascript api

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, custom-functions-excel

I'm newly developing with the office.js and I would like to know if there is a way to convert serial numbers (Date Values) into date formatted using Excel Javascript API.

I have this custom function:

```
/*
 * @customfunction
 * @param {number} first
 * @param {number} second
 * @param {string} third
 * @returns {number[][]}
 */

  function GETDADOS(first, second, third) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve){
      $.ajax({
        ...
        //HTTP requisition
        ...
        }
      });
    })
    return promise.then(function(result){
      var data = result
      var resp = JSON.parse(data)
      return resp
    })
  })
  };
```

That provides me this output:

> [[44225,1.8541],[44232,1.874],[44239,1.94]]

The first column is the date value to be transformed.

> EX: US 35062 -> 12/29/2021, UK 35062 -> 29/12/2021

I saw this way but I'm feeling a little bit confused:

[convert date serial number to date using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229494/converting-excel-date-serial-number-to-date-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You may use Excel JavaScript API to call built-in Excel worksheet function [TEXT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

```js
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    var res = context.workbook.functions.text(44225, "mm/dd/yy");
    res.load("value");
    await context.sync();
    console.log(res.value); // "01/29/21"
  });
```

Note that to call Excel JavaScript APIs from your custom function, you'll need to use a shared JavaScript runtime. See [Configure your Office Add-in to use a shared JavaScript runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) for more details.