# Excel file date format is wrong after importing

Tags: angular, exceljs

I'm using `ExcelJs` in my `Angular 7` app, where I have a function to import excel file. The problem is when I `console.log` the data from the worksheet the date formats are wrong for e.g. the cell contains `2021.11.30 12:00:00` but in the log it shows `44530.5`.

here is the code for importing the file:

```
    let workBook = null;
    let jsonData = null;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = ev.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const data = reader.result;
      workBook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
      jsonData = workBook.SheetNames.reduce((initial, name) => {
        const sheet = workBook.Sheets[name];
        initial[name] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
        return initial;
      }, {});
      const dataString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
      console.log('data: ', dataString);  <-- this shows the data from worksheet
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = dataString.slice(0, 30000).concat("....");
      // this.setDownload(dataString);
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }
```

In the worksheet the cell is set to Date.
Any ideas what can I do to fix the issue with the wrong date format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Excel Date Serial Number to Date using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229494/converting-excel-date-serial-number-to-date-using-javascript)

Comment: excel actually stores dates as a number, and just formats it to make it look nice. So when you import a excel file with dates, you get the number, and have to convert it to javascript format. Take a look at the link above, I think that will help you :)

Comment: thanks I'll take a look