# How to convert Excel Hour Serial Number to the H:M format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

Inside of Excel file, I have an `hour:minute` time format, example of one value from that excel file is: `"19:15"`

After uploading that file to my application, it is being read as `"0.8020833333333334"`.

I want to convert that value from column (`"0.8020833333333334"`) to get hours and minutes.

Here's what I have accomplished so far:

```
const extractTime = new Date(Math.round((0.8020833333333334 - 25569) * 864e5));
```

The result is not what I expected.

How can I convert this number to get the hour as 19, and minutes as 15?

Comment: What type of excel file is it? .csv , .xlsx? or something else? Is it a option for you to use libraries? Also can you post the code how you're extracting time from excel file?

Comment: The library I am using is exceljs. When uploaded, the hour 19:15 is read as its native serial number which is 0.8020833333333334.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been "digging" around StackOverflow's questions about this, and my answer is based on [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229494/converting-excel-date-serial-number-to-date-using-javascript) answers, as well as [ECMA's date time](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range). Mostly my answer is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16233621/12826055).

In the comments you can see, that there will be problems if you're working with date-time values, based on this comment:

> This anwer is wrong for 2 reasons: 1) the final Date constructor in
> the return value will create the time as a local time - results will
> differ depending on the client. 2) the solution does not take the 1900
> leap year bug into account. I believe my solutions solves both issues. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57184486/12826055

And in case someone is working with date-time format, I would suggest using the answer which is linked inside of quotes, but in the case you only have TIME (19:30 -> 0.8020833333333334) and similar, it will be correct to use the code below.

Code:

```
var serial = 0.8020833333333334
var fractional_day = serial - Math.floor(serial) + 0.0000001;
 var total_seconds = Math.floor(86400 * fractional_day);
 
 var seconds = total_seconds % 60;

   total_seconds -= seconds;

   var hours = Math.floor(total_seconds / (60 * 60));
   var minutes = Math.floor(total_seconds / 60) % 60;

console.log(hours)
console.log(minutes)
```

Outputs:

```
19
15
```